# List the difference between two kernels

Tags: android, linux

I have two Linux kernels with me. One is the Android Linux Kernel and the other is the normal Linux Kernel. I would like to know how to get the differences between them and list them on a file. I don't want to see the differences in the source files but I just want to have an indication that this file is different. More clearly I would like to list the files which are different in both the kernel directories.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

diff has an option, `-q` that only tells you if the files differ. You could use that.

Alternatively, you can generate the md5sum of each file using:

```
find . -type f -exec md5sum {} \;
```

Do this for both trees, output to two files, and diff the files.

Answer (score -1):

Android Kernel:
Android relies on Linux version 2.6 for core system services such as security, memory management, process management, network stack, and driver model. The kernel also acts as an abstraction layer between the hardware and the rest of the software stack.
Linux kernel:

The Linux kernel is an operating system kernel used by the Linux family of Unix-like operating systems.[6] It is one of the most prominent examples of free and open source software.[7]

The Linux kernel is released under the GNU General Public License version 2 (GPLv2)[4] (plus some firmware images with various non-free licenses), and is developed by contributors worldwide. Day-to-day development takes place on the Linux kernel mailing list.